# How do I ensure that my program halts until my axios requests have been resolved?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, async-await, axios

I'm working on a project using React as my front-end. When I create an item, my intention is to first send a request to my server to create the item (using only the textual form data) and then to send an individual request per image upload.

```
// handles item creation
handleCreate = async (data) => {
    let id = await axios({
                            method: 'post',
                            url: <item_creation_URL>,
                            data: data
                        })
                        .then(res => {
                            return res.data();
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            this.handleErrors(err);
                        })
    return id;
}

// handles image uploads for a specific item
handleUpload = async (fd, itemId) => {
    let response = await axios({
                                 method: 'post',
                                 url: <img_upload_URL>,
                                 headers: {
                                     'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
                                 },
                                 data: fd
                               })
                               .then(res => {
                                   return res;
                               })
                               .catch(err => {
                                   this.handleErrors(err.response.data);
                               });
    return response;
}

// prepares and sends the data to the server to create a new item
handleSubmit = event => {

    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ loading: true });

    // data needed to make an item on firebase
    const itemData = {
        name       : this.state.name,
        desc       : this.state.desc,
        cover      : this.state.coverImgIndex,
        visibleTo  : this.state.visibleTo,
        assignedTo : this.state.assignedTo,
        photos     : this.state.photos
    }

    // create a new item using the data
    let itemId = this.handleCreate(itemData);

    // upload the photos
    if (!this.state.errors){
        for (let i=0; i < this.state.uploadedFiles.length; i++) {
            let file = this.state.uploadedFiles[i];
            let fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', file, file.name);

            // send each file as its own upload request
            this.handleUpload(fd, itemId);

            if (this.state.errors) break;
        }
    }

    // submission was successful
    if (!this.state.errors){
        this.setState({ loading : false });
    }
}
```

I did some research online and thought I could achieve the desired effect by wrapping each axios request in an `async` block with an `await`.
However, execution seems to progress without waiting for each request to finish.

I'm fairly new to using `Promise`s in Javascript. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: An `async` function must be `await`ed as well. `handle*` is `await`ing the axios calls, but your loop isn't `await`ing the `handle*` calls.

Comment: @deceze I did try writing ```let itemId = await this.handleCreate(itemData);``` but I got the error ```Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function```

Comment: Self explanatory error message, whatever function you use `await` in needs `async` in its signature. You've already done that, like _inside_ the `handleCreate` function. Gotta do it where you're actually calling it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you made `handleCreate()` and `handleUpload()` functions asynchronous.
therefore, when you call these functions use `await` if you should go ahead after axios end.

**Like this**

```
// handles item creation
handleCreate = async data => {
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      method: "post",
      url: `<item_creation_URL>`,
      data: data
    });
    return res.data();
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
};

// handles image uploads for a specific item
handleUpload = async (fd, itemId) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      method: "post",
      url: `<img_upload_URL>`,
      headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data"
      },
      data: fd
    });
    return res;
  } catch (err) {
    throw err.response.data;
  }
};

// prepares and sends the data to the server to create a new item
handleSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  // data needed to make an item on firebase
  const { name, desc, cover, visibleTo, assignedTo, photos } = this.state;
  this.setState({ loading: true });
  this._asyncSubmit({ name, desc, cover, visibleTo, assignedTo, photos });
};

_asyncSubmit = async itemData => {
  try {
    // create a new item using the data
    const itemId = await this.handleCreate(itemData);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.uploadedFiles.length; i++) {
      const file = this.state.uploadedFiles[i];
      let fd = new FormData();
      fd.append("file", file, file.name);
      // send each file as its own upload request
      await this.handleUpload(fd, itemId);
    }
  } catch(err) {
    // you can handle errors here
    this.handleErrors(err);
  }
  this.setState({ loading: false });
};
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm still getting the error `Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function` for the line `const itemId = await this.handleCreate(itemData);`

Comment: I had to make a few minor changes because of the way my server responds, but it's working now- thank you very much!